# Transform rows to columns and join them by dates

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I'm trying to add daily weather information to a data frame on R , so  df1 + df2 = df3 is the objetive. I thougth that subseting df2 by dates on df1, collapsing df2 and rbind.fill them with df1 would be the way, but I'm having trouble.

```
date2 <- c('2014-06-03','2017-05-20')
date  <- c('2014-06-01','2017-05-15')
df1 <- data.frame(date,date2)
date

#> df1
#        date      date2
#1 2014-06-01 2014-06-03
#2 2017-05-15 2017-05-20

date3 <- c('2014-06-01','2014-06-02','2014-06-03','2017-05-15','2017-05-16','2017-05-17','2017-05-18','2017-05-19','2017-05-20')
rain  <-  c(3,            4,               3,          5,           5,            6,         7,           6         ,6)
sun <- c (  10,10,10, 15,15,15,16,15,15)
df2 <- data.frame(date3,rain,sun)

#> df2
#       date3 rain sun
#1 2014-06-01    3  10
#2 2014-06-02    4  10
#3 2014-06-03    3  10
#4 2017-05-15    5  15
#5 2017-05-16    5  15
#6 2017-05-17    6  15
#7 2017-05-18    7  16
#8 2017-05-19    6  15
#9 2017-05-20    6  15

rain_day1 <- c(3,5)
rain_day2 <- c(4,5)
rain_day3 <- c(3,6)
rain_day4 <- c(NA,7)
rain_day5 <- c(NA,6)
rain_day6 <- c(NA,6)
sun_day1 <- c(10,15)
sun_day2 <- c(10,15)
sun_day3 <- c(10,15)
sun_day4 <- c(NA,15)
sun_day5 <- c(NA,16)
sun_day6 <- c(NA,15)
date5 <- c('2014-06-03','2017-05-20')
date4  <- c('2014-06-01','2017-05-15')
df3 <- data.frame(date4,date5,rain_day1,sun_day1,rain_day2,sun_day2,rain_day3,sun_day3,rain_day4,sun_day4,rain_day5,sun_day5,rain_day6,sun_day6)

#> df3
#      date4      date5 rain_day1 sun_day1 rain_day2 sun_day2 rain_day3 sun_day3 rain_day4 sun_day4
#1 2014-06-01 2014-06-03         3       10         4       10         3       10        NA       NA
#2 2017-05-15 2017-05-20         5       15         5       15         6       15         7       15
#  rain_day5 sun_day5 rain_day6 sun_day6
#1        NA       NA        NA       NA
#2         6       16         6       15
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: not clear. what is the data in rows and in columns finally

Comment: on df1 one row have two dates an initial and a final date. on df2 each date is the weather on that day, on df3 (the result) is the weather on each day for the two dates of df1. So on df3, sun_day1 is the value for sun on day 1 (2014-06-01) and so on until last day (2014-06-03) . In case there would be more days on one row than another, it should be fill with NA.

Comment: probably transpose using t(df) and join using a merge

Comment: tryCatch(library("plyr") , 
         error = function(e) {
           install.packages("plyr")
           library("plyr")
         }
)
dff <- df2[ which( df2$date3 <= df1$date2[1] ) , ]
dff <- dff[ which( dff$date3 >= df1$date[1] ) , ]

rbind.fill(df1[1,],as.data.frame(t(unlist(dff))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I thougth that subseting df2 by dates on df1, collapsing df2 and rbind.fill them with df1 would be the way".... it took longer than wanted, but I made it !

```
lapply(df1, class)
df1$date <- sapply( df1$date , function(x) as.character(x) ) 
df1$date2 <- sapply( df1$date2 , function(x) as.character(x) ) 
lapply(df2, class)
df2$date3 <- sapply( df2$date3 , function(x) as.character(x) ) 
lapply(df3, class)
df3$date4 <- sapply( df3$date4 , function(x) as.character(x) ) 
df3$date5 <- sapply( df3$date5 , function(x) as.character(x) ) 


tryCatch(library("plyr") , 
         error = function(e) {
           install.packages("plyr")
           library("plyr")
         }
)
df4 <- df1
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  dff <- df2[ which( df2$date3 <= df1$date2[i] ) , ]
  dff <- dff[ which( dff$date3 >= df1$date[i] ) , ]
  dff <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(dff)))
  colnames(dff)[1] <- "date"
  df5 <- merge(x = df1, y = dff, by = "date")
  df5 <- rbind.fill(df4,df5)
  df5<-df5[-1,]
  df4 <- df5
} 

df5 <- df5[, -grep("^date3", colnames(df5))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I welcome any improvement on my pipe prose, I'm working on it.

```
library(magrittr)
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df1$date2 <- as.Date(df1$date2)
df2$date3 <- as.Date(df2$date3)
df2 %<>% setNames(c("date3","rain_day","sun_day"))
row_list <- df1 %>% apply(1,function(x){ df2 %>%
                                   subset(date3 >= x["date"] & date3 <= x["date2"]) %>%     # subsetting
                                   "["(2:3) %>%                                             # selecting relevant column
                                   unlist}) %>%                                             # spearding all data into a vector
  sapply(.,function(x){x[rep(c(0,length(x)/2),length(x)/2)+rep(1:(length(x)/2),each=2)]})   # reordering

row_names <- row_list %>% sapply(length) %>% which.max %>% "[["(row_list,.) %>% names() # taking the names from longest list
row_list %>% sapply(function(x){c(x,rep(NA,max(sapply(.,length))-length(x)))}) %>% # complete with NAs
 t %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(row_names) %>% cbind(df1,.)                     # transpose, convert, set names and append to df1
#         date      date2 rain_day1 sun_day1 rain_day2 sun_day2 rain_day3 sun_day3 rain_day4 sun_day4 rain_day5 sun_day5 rain_day6 sun_day6
# 1 2014-06-01 2014-06-03         3       10         4       10         3       10        NA       NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
# 2 2017-05-15 2017-05-20         5       15         5       15         6       15         7       16         6       15         6       15
```